# How to get the CPU ID using .NET CORE?

Tags: .net-core

I need to get the hardware ID (CPU ID) of the host using .NET Core 2. How can this be done?

The System.Management class from .NET has not been ported to .NET Core. Is there a cross-platform alternative to this (macOS, Linux, and Windows)?

Comment: Thank you guys. I updated the question to make it more clear. By Hardware ID, I mean any ID from Hardware except Hard Drive. I can work with CPU ID, Motherboard Serial number, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Classes from `System.Management` namespace are available to `.NET Core` applications via [Windows Compatibility Pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/windows-compat-pack) developed by Microsoft. You can reference either whole [Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility) metapackage, or (if you don't need other classes) just standalone [System.Management](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/) package.

Comment: Thank you @Nuf, I a aware of that. But my application is built to run in Mac and Linux. The Compatibility Pack is not going to work for me.

Comment: There is a [plan](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24790) to support `System.Management` on Linux, but probably not anytime soon :-(

Comment: .net core 3.1 is almost released. still there is nothing regarding this yet supported in .net core while we have libraries in java like oshi which help in it

Comment: NET Core is cross-platform, but COM/WMI are Windows-specific. Try Nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management/